# SQLite set multiple values to specific foreign key

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, multivalue

I have two tables in SQLite, `article` and `keyword` table. In the `article` table, I have some columns like article name, article year ... and also article keyword. I set the article keyword column as a foreign key and connect it to the keyword table.

But there is more than one keyword from the `keyword` table belonging to a specific article.

For example in the keyword table:

```
key_id    keyword 
-------------------
  1       xxx 
  2       yyy
  3       zzz
```

and in the `article` table and keyword column for specific row, I need xxx and yyy. So I should connect it by key_id 1 and 2. how I can do this?

Set multiple foreign key from specific table.

Comment: Post sample data for both tables and expected results to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

In relational database system, you normally need a third table to model the one-to-many relationship between an article and its keywords. You can name your table `article_keyword`, and it shall have two columns, article_id and keyword_id:

```
article_id  keyword_id
1           1
1           2
1           3
2           2
2           3
...         ...
```